# Install non-editable tag/branch from Git repo with pip

Tags: pip

I would like to install a non-editable (e.g. no `-e` option) tag or branch from a Git repo using [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/) and cannot seem to find out how to do it.

If I do this:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/django/django.git@1.2.5#egg=django
```

It just installs Django `master` branch and not the `1.2.5` tag. I know that I can install it using the `-e` option but I don't want to fill up my `src` dir with packages I am not modifying. This seems like it should be straightforward thing to do but I can't seem how to do it...

Is this possible? If so, how can I accomplish it?

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are probably using an old pip version. Try upgrading your pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

There was an [issue to it](https://bitbucket.org/ianb/pip/issue/49), and I just tried version 0.8.2 (the latest at the moment) and it works ;-)

Comment: That was it! Oddly enough I had version 0.8.1 locally but 0.8.2 on my server, I guess I forgot to upgrade my local virtualenv. Thanks for the tip.