# How to point pip at a Mercurial branch?

Tags: python, mercurial, pip

I'm trying to install my application via pip to a virtualenv for testing.

Works fine for installing the `default` or `tip` like so:

```
pip install -e hg+https://username@bitbucket.org/username/app_name#egg=app_name
```

But is there any way to point to a branch, rather than just getting the tip. Not sure if this would be a mercurial thing, bitbucket, or pip.

Bitbucket allows for downloading of a tagged version of the code, but I can only get it to work while logged into the browser. I tried installing from a `tag` tar.gz like so:

```
pip install https://username@bitbucket.org/username/app_name/get/bbc4286a75db.tar.gz
```

but even after entering my password it returns a 401 Unauthorized (Its a Private Repo)

Comment: Did you try `username:password@bitbucket.org`?

Comment: Have you tried the @tag/branch/node thing? This works well on my repos (not on bitbucket) hg+ssh://user@myserver//home/user/repos/myproject/@django14#egg=myproject-dev

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In official pip documentation in section [VCS Support](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support):

> Mercurial
>
> The supported schemes are: hg+http, hg+https, hg+static-http and
>   hg+ssh:
>
> ```
> -e hg+http://hg.myproject.org/MyProject/#egg=MyProject
> -e hg+https://hg.myproject.org/MyProject/#egg=MyProject
> -e hg+ssh://hg@myproject.org/MyProject/#egg=MyProject
> ```
>
> You can also specify a revision number, a revision hash, a tag name or
>   a local branch name:
>
> ```
> -e hg+http://hg.myproject.org/MyProject/@da39a3ee5e6b#egg=MyProject
> -e hg+http://hg.myproject.org/MyProject/@2019#egg=MyProject
> -e hg+http://hg.myproject.org/MyProject/@v1.0#egg=MyProject
> -e hg+http://hg.myproject.org/MyProject/@special_feature#egg=MyProject
> ```

The syntax is the same when specifying repo at the command line

```
pip install -e hg+http://hg.myproject.org/MyProject/@special_feature#egg=MyProject
```

and it works when not using `-e` option [starting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5008162/95735) from version 0.8.2.