# Automated deployment and update of Python-based Software with pip

Tags: python, git, deployment, mercurial, pip

We have a relatively large number of machines in a cluster that run a certain Python-based software for computation in an academic research environment. In order to keep the code base up to date, we are using a build server which makes the current code base available in a directory each time we update a dedicated deployment tag on our Mercurial server. Each machine part of the cluster runs a daily `rsync` script that just synchronises with the deployment directory on the build server (if there's anything to sync) and restart the process if the code base was updated.

Now this approach I find a bit dated and a slight overkill, and would like to optimise in the following way:

- Get rid of the build server as all it actually does is clone the latest code base that has a certain tag attached - it doesn't actually compile or do any additional checks (such as testing) on the code base at all. This would also reduce some pain for us as it'd be one less server to maintain and worry about.
- Instad of having the build server, I would like to pull straight from our Mercurial server which hosts the code already. This would reduce the need to duplicate the code base each time we update the deployment tag.

Now I had a bit of a read before on how to install / deploy Python-based software with `pip` (e.g., [How to point pip at a Mercurial branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262306/how-to-point-pip-at-a-mercurial-branch)). It seems to be the right choice as it supports installing packages straight from a code repository. However, I ran into a few problems that I would need help with. The requirements I have are as follows:

- Use Mercurial as a source.
- Automated background process to update and install into a custom directory on the file system.
- Only pull and update from the repository if there is a new version available.

The following command seems to *almost* do what I need:

```
pip install -e hg+https://authkey:anypw@mymercurialserver.hostname.com/Code/package@deployment#egg=package --upgrade --src ~/proj
```

It pulls the package from the Mercurial server, picks the code base with the tag "deployment" and installs it into `proj` inside the user's home directory.

The problem, however, is that regardless whether there is an update available or not, `pip` always uninstalls `package` and reinstalls it. This makes it difficult to decide whether the process needs to be restarted or not if nothing actually changed. In addition, `pip` always gets stuck with the the message that `hg clone in ./proj/yarely exists with URL...` and asks me: `What to do?  (s)witch, (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup`. Now this is not ideal, as (1) it would be an automated process without user prompt, and, (2) it should only pull the repository if there was an update in the first place to reduce traffic in the network and not overload our Mercurial server. I believe that in this case, a `pull` instead of `clone` if there was a local copy of the repository already would be more appropriate and potentially solve the problem.

I wasn't able to find an elegant and nice solution to this problem. Does anyone have a pointer or suggestion how this could be achieved?

Comment: Well, frankly speaking your approach is not much is not a large step forward  when is comes to being "dated". It you have a cluster, there are nice solutions to application deployments to machines. The "docker universe" alone has many solutions to your problem. Software deployment is BTW not the right topic for SO.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I considered Docker though we are running some platform-dependent code and rely on things like PyObjC so it seemed like it Docker wouldn't have been the perfect solution in that case either. Perhaps the software is a little dated after all so I'm just trying to optimise the previous approach as well as possible :)